# Anyone know a good replacement for the mod_layout apache module?

Tags: html, apache, apache-modules

I've been using the mod_layout module for my apache server for a very long time ... recently, however, it's not been working quite right.

Rather than try to get the module fixed (I think the author has abandoned it), I'd like to find a different options.

Basically, mod_layout let's me insert test and/or files into html on the fly.  I can insert text at the beginning, end, or after specific text that appears in the html.

Comment: maybe you could try an ESI gate like varnish-esi?

Comment: well, google: https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ESIfeatures